# Python Numpy: Coalesce and return first nonzero observation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coalesce

I am currently new to NumPy, but very proficient with SQL.
I used a function called `coalesce` in SQL, which I was disappointed not to find in NumPy. I need this function to create a third array `want` from 2 arrays i.e. `array1` and `array2`, where zero/ missing observations in `array1` are replaced by observations in `array2` under the same address/Location. I can't figure out how to use `np.where`?

Once this task is accomplished, I would like to take the lower diagonal of this array `want` and then populate a final array `want2` noting the ***first non-zero*** observation. If all observations i.e. `coalesce(array1, array2)` returns missing or 0 in `want2`, then assign by default zero.

I have written an example demonstrating the desired behavior.

```
import numpy as np
array1= np.array(([-10,0,20],[-1,0,0],[0,34,-50]))
array2= np.array(([10,10,50],[10,0,25],[50,45,0]))

# Coalesce array1,array2 i.e. get the first non-zero value from array1, then from array2. 
# if array1 is empty or zero, then populate table want with values from array2 under same address
want=np.tril(np.array(([-10,10,20],[-1,0,25],[50,34,-50])))

print(array1)
print(array2)
print(want)

# print first instance of nonzero observation from each column of table want
want2=np.array([-10,34,-50])
print(want2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Coalesce": use `putmask` to replace values equal to zero with values from `array2`:

```
want = array1.copy()
np.putmask(array1.copy(), array1==0, array2)
```

First nonzero element of each column of `np.tril(want)`:

```
where_nonzero = np.where(np.tril(want) != 0)

"""For the where array, get the indices of only 
the first index for each column"""
first_indices = np.unique(where_nonzero[1], return_index=True)[1]

# Get the values from want for those indices
want2 = want[(where_nonzero[0][first_indices], where_nonzero[1][first_indices])]
```